# Merge two arrays with key , and the second array being an object inside the 1st array

Tags: javascript

Say i have 2 arrays arr1, arr2:

```
var arr1 = [{id:1, name:2}, {id:2, name:3}, {id:3, name:2}];
var arr2 = [{orgid:2, desc:'2'},{orgid:1, desc:'1'},{orgid:1, desc:'3'}]
```

I want to achieve the below:

```
var arr3 = [{id:1, name:2, org: [{desc:'1'},{ desc:'3'}]},{id:2, name:3, org: {desc:'2'}} , {id:3, name:2, org: []}]
```

I have tried the below:

```
const map = new Map();
arr1.forEach(item => map.set(item.id, item));
arr2.forEach(item => map.set(item.orgid, {...map.get(item.orgid), ...item}));
```

which gives me something like:

```
[{"id":1,"name":2,"orgid":1,"desc":"1"}, {"id":2,"name":3,"orgid":2,"desc":"2"}]
```

so id and orgId are the same, its the key that i m using to merge the arrays.

There is a slight change, i may expect multiple objects for same orgId in arr2, which should map to an array of org in arr3.

Also there could be no orgId present in arr2, which would populate a blank org[] in arr3

Comment: What have you tried ? Post it so that others can help you with it.

Comment: Edited the post with what i have tried, however i am trying to create arr3

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Check again my answer please. I have updated.

Answer (score 2):

You could collect org with a `Map` and map the array with additional property.

```js
const
    arr1 = [{ id: 1, name: 2 }, { id: 2, name: 3 }],
    arr2 = [{ orgid: 2, desc: '2' }, { orgid: 1, desc: '1' }, { orgid: 1, desc: '3' }],
    map2 = arr2.reduce((m, { orgid, ...o }) => m.set(orgid, m.has(orgid)
        ? [].concat(m.get(orgid), o)
        : o
    ), new Map),
    result = arr1.map(o => ({ ...o, org: map2.get(o.id) || [] }));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works however if i have arr2 like var arr2 = [{orgid:2, desc:'2'},{orgid:1, desc:'1'},{orgid:1, desc:'3'}], then it only maps orgid:1, desc:'3' in arr3, i was trying to see if  i can map both objects as an array

Comment: it takes all items from the first array. what result do you want with non matching items?

Comment: [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": 2,
    "org": [{
      "desc": "1"
    },
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": 3,
    "org": {
      "desc": "2"
    }
  }
]

Comment: assuming, you want all matched items, if more than one in an array or a single object. please see edit.

Comment: Yes This works like a charm, however for all the unmatched items , i wanted an empty org[]

Answer (score 0):

You can use rest syntax to remove the `orgid` property and add the rest of the properties under another key.

```js
var arr1 = [{id:1, name:2}, {id:2, name:3}];
var arr2 = [{orgid:2, desc:'2'},{orgid:1, desc:'1'}]
const map = new Map();
arr1.forEach(item => map.set(item.id, item));
arr2.forEach(({orgid, ...rest}) => map.set(orgid, {...map.get(orgid), org: rest}));
console.log([...map.values()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the orgs and then look them up when mapping.

```js
const
  arr1 = [ { id: 1, name: 2 }, { id: 2, name: 3 } ],
  arr2 = [ { orgid: 2, desc: '2' }, { orgid: 1, desc: '1' } ],
  orgs = arr2.reduce((acc, { orgid, ...rest }) => ({ ...acc, [orgid]: { ...rest } }), {}),
  arr3 = arr1.map(({ id, ...rest }) => ({ id, ...rest, org: orgs[id] }));

console.log(arr3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution:

```
var arr1 = [{id:1, name:2}, {id:2, name:3}];
var arr2 = [{orgid:2, desc:'2'},{orgid:1, desc:'1'}]

var arr3 = arr1.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      org: ({ desc: arr2.find(o => o.orgid === item.id)?.desc || null })
    }))
```

```js
var arr1 = [{id:1, name:2}, {id:2, name:3}];
var arr2 = [{orgid:2, desc:'2'},{orgid:1, desc:'1'}]

const arr3 = arr1.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  org: ({ desc: arr2.find(o => o.orgid === item.id)?.desc || null })
}))

console.log(arr3)
```